# PHP Single App / Dual Database - Session values lost after header redirect in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, wamp

**Scenario**

I am trying to correct an issue with an application that is populating user in a session variable in Internet Explorer using a dual db, single application.  I have a unique configuration for a PHP application that is based on the question I asked previously.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/34841867/1691103

I am using a single folder structure that is addressable by the database name.  **My virtual host name equals the database name being accessed**.  If I try to access localhost or my computer name I purposely prevent this request since those dbnames do not exist.

```
http://app      --> loads data from app database
http://app_demo --> loads data from app_demo database
```

**app** is the name of the single application directory

Now, when I log in to my application via `http://app` I can do so in Firefox.  Additionally, I can also log into my app via `http://app_demo` in Firefox.  I see the logged in user via the session variable.

**Problem**

In Internet Explorer my app does not show the logged in user in the Session when accessed via `http://app_demo` despite being able to do so when accessed via `http://app`

When I access `http://app_demo` in Internet Explorer the session is populated right before index.php header redirect but is cleared right after I try to see the value in index.php.

**Question**

What do I need to do to make login work for both hostnames in IE?

**Windows Hosts File**

```
127.0.0.1       app
127.0.0.1       app_demo
```

**Apache Virtual Hosts Definition**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/app"
    ServerName App
    ServerAlias App
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/app">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/app"
    ServerName app_demo
    ServerAlias app_demo
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/app">
          AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    {
        require_once('session.php');
    }
    else if (isset($_SESSION['expire']))
    { 
        $expire = $_SESSION['expire'];
        session_destroy();
        echo $expire;
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
    }     
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
    session_cache_limiter ('private, must-revalidate');
    session_start();
?>
```

**authenticate.php**

```
 <?php
            require_once('session.php');
            require_once('usermanager.php');

            $username = isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : '';
            $password = isset($_POST['password'])? $_POST['password'] : '';


            if ($username == '' or $password == '')
            {
                    header('Location: login.php?err=1');    
                    return;
            }

            $userManager = new UserManager($username, $password);
            if (!$userManager->isValidUserName($username))
            {
                    header('Location: login.php?err=2');
                    return;
            }
            else
            {
                    $confirmed = $userManager->confirmUserNamePassword($username, $password);
                    if (!$confirmed)
                    {     
                        header('Location: login.php?err=3');    
                        return;                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userManager->getUserID($username, $password);
                        $_SESSION['userrole'] = $userManager->getUserRole($username, $password);
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true; 
                        $_SESSION['lastnamefirstname'] = $userManager->getLastNameFirstName($username, $password);
                        header('Location: index.php');
                        exit;
                    }
            }

    ?>
```